# Converting Visual Studio 2008 project to Visual Studio 2013

Tags: .net, xaml, visual-studio-2013, ribbon, project-conversion

**SORRY FOR THE DOUBLE POST**

I'm trying to convert a simple project of an application VS2008 **.NET FRAMEWORK 3.5** has Ribbon to VS2013 **.NET FRAMEWORK 4.5**.

However, I cant find any property that fits just like the **RibbonApplicationMenu.Command**, **RibbonApplicationMenu.Footer**, **RibbonApplicationMenu.Header**, or any **RibbonCommand**.

Can someone help me? Why can not use these properties in my new application in 2013? There is any way to use .Command/RibbonCommand properties ?

I searched but did not find explanations.

There is my code example below:

```
<r:RibbonWindow
xmlns:r="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.Ribbon;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Ribbon"
....
 ....
  ....

<r:Ribbon.ApplicationMenu>
  <r:RibbonApplicationMenu Name="menApplication">
    <r:RibbonApplicationMenu.Command> <--------DO NOT WORK
      <r:RibbonCommand /> <--------DO NOT WORK
    </r:RibbonApplicationMenu.Command>
    <r:RibbonApplicationMenu.Footer><--------DO NOT WORK
      <Button/>
    </r:RibbonApplicationMenu.Footer>
    <r:RibbonApplicationMenuItem >
  </r:RibbonApplicationMenuItem>
</r:Ribbon.ApplicationMenu>
</r:RibbonWindow>
```

Comment: The attachable property 'Command' was not found in type 'RibbonApplicationMenu'.

Answer (score 0):

If I read it correctly, you should try using bindings for them instead of child elements. See the following:

```
<r:RibbonWindow xmlns:r="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.Ribbon;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Ribbon"
....
....
....
    <r:Ribbon.ApplicationMenu>
      <r:RibbonApplicationMenu Name="menApplication" Command="{Binding YourMethod}"/>
      <r:RibbonApplicationMenu.FooterPaneContent>
        <r:RibbonButton ... />
      </r:RibbonApplicationMenu.FooterPaneContent>
      <r:RibbonApplicationMenuItem ... />
    </r:Ribbon.ApplicationMenu>
</r:RibbonWindow>
```